# Not able to datepicker pop in ng-grid input

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

grid
i trying to get date picker in ng-grid
not able to get date picker pop only up and down button are showing and also i need default value in each input below is my plunker link
help is need 
Thanks in advance

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50,dob:"1/08/1989"},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43,dob:"1/07/1989"},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27,dob:"23/09/1988"},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29,dob:"26/09/1988"},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34,dob:"05/05/1987"}];  
    $scope.gridOptions = { 
        data: 'myData',
        enableCellEdit:true,
        enableCellSelection:true,
        enableColumnResize:true,
        columnDefs: [{field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'}, 
        {field:'age', displayName:'Age'},
        {field:'dob', displayName:'DOB',enableCellEdit:true,cellTemplate:'<input type="date"/>'}]
    };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/O5llvsl2nS0OcRNU7XON?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Since every browser has it's own implementation of date control, not every browser will show the date pop up, so as a solution I would suggest using a third party plugin like jQueryUI [Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) as your date control, this way you get same functionality across all browsers.

so to make a long story short:

1. Create a directive for your Datepicker plugin.
2. Don't forget to add ng-model to input element for your default values.

Example:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50,dob:"1/08/1989"},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43,dob:"1/07/1989"},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27,dob:"23/09/1988"},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29,dob:"26/09/1988"},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34,dob:"05/05/1987"}];  
    $scope.gridOptions = { 
        data: 'myData',
        enableCellEdit:true,
        enableCellSelection:true,
        enableColumnResize:true,
        columnDefs: [{field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'}, 
        {field:'age', displayName:'Age'},
        {field:'dob', displayName:'DOB',
        cellTemplate:'<input jquery-datepicker="" type="text" ng-model="row.entity.dob"/>'}]
    };
```

Live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/6h5JIJeCkARNGWQgzeJ9?p=preview

Comment: thank you but when i try to change the month in datepicker popup i am getting error like 'Uncaught Missing instance data for this datepicker' i got this error after adding 'enableCellEditOnFocus: true,'

Comment: but there is no such property called "enableCellEditOnFocus", where did you add this property?

Comment: i got that property from  'https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Defining-columns' any how after adding property  cellEditableCondition: 'row.entity.editable', it is working for Thank you very much for your answer